# Selenium does not work on ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to run the following code on virtual machine with ubuntu 16.04:

```
import time
import time from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
```

But an error is returned, what do I do wrong? Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test_driver.py", line 4, in
> <module>
>     driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
> line 68, in __init__
>     self.service.start()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 76, in start
>     stdin=PIPE)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
>     restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
>     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg) OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I'm using python 3.5.2 and selenium-standalone@6.12.0

Comment: download the correct version of chromedriver for your platform

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a *typo* in the *version* information you have shared as you have mentioned **selenium-standalone@6.12.0** and the latest *Selenium* release being **selenium-server-standalone-3.10.0** and is used with the *Selenium Java Client*.

As you are working with *Selenium Python Client* you have upgrade the *Selenium Python Client* version from the *Command Line Interface(CLI)* through `pip` command which will uninstall the current *Selenium Python Client* version and install the latest *Selenium Python Client* version as follows :

```
C:\Users\Niki>pip install -U selenium
Collecting selenium
  Downloading selenium-3.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (943kB)
    100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 952kB 102kB/s
Installing collected packages: selenium
  Found existing installation: selenium 3.7.0
    Uninstalling selenium-3.7.0:
      Successfully uninstalled selenium-3.7.0
Successfully installed selenium-3.10.0
```

Now, you have to download the latest *ChromeDriver* from [*ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome*](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) page, ensure your *Chrome Browser* version is in sync with *ChromeDriver*  and finally to initialize the *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* you can use the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```